# Jboss AS / Tomcat debian deploy: JSF FileNotFoundException

Tags: jsf, jboss, richfaces, debian

Short intro:

Im trying to deploy a jsf 2.1 project on Jboss AS 7 (tryed also on Tomcat 7). The deploy is working without any issues but when I try to access the site css, images and javascript cannot be found and I get tons of the following exception type from the logs:

```
0:04:58,261 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[Faces Servlet]] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-21) Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException: /projectName/rfRes/calendarIcon.png.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource
```

In the browser it looks like:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

In the template an image for example looks like:

```
<h:graphicImage library="images" name="logo.png" />
```

The generated path from faces to resources:

```
<img src="/projectName/javax.faces.resource/logo.png.xhtml;jsessionid=30AEAD88CADB047E3DFBDDA372732F08?ln=images">
```

Path to images:

```
WebContent/resources/images
```

I have tryed to deploy it with different configurations: Jboss 7.0/7.1, Tomcat 6/7, Java 6/7. But it works only for my local deployment and not for the debian. One solution would be to just put everywhere the direct path to the resources without using jsf but what to do with richfaces images and everything... .

**Project and System configuration:**

Java 7
Hibernate 3
Jsf 2.1
Richfaces 4.2
Debian 6

**faces config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <application> 
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en_EN</default-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>language</base-name>
            <var>language</var>
        </resource-bundle>
        <factory>
            <exception-handler-factory>
                package.ViewExceptionHandlerFactory
            </exception-handler-factory>
        </factory>
        <lifecycle>
            <phase-listener>package.AuthListener</phase-listener>
        </lifecycle>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app metadata-complete="true" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>Name</display-name>
    <servlet id="JSF_Front_Controller_Servlet">
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>package.services</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <display-name>AuthFilter</display-name>
        <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>package.AuthFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/view/user/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <display-name>HibernateFilter</display-name>
        <filter-name>HibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>package.HibernateFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>package.HibernateListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>view/start.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>shadow</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/services/payment/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

**Update 1**

It seems to be an server issue. Im running debian 6 with apache2 and the following virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Proxy *>
 Order deny,allow
 Allow from all
</Proxy>

 RewriteEngine On
 ProxyPreserveHost On

 RewriteRule ^/(.*)$  http://127.0.0.1:8080/project-name/$1 [P]

ServerName url.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The rewriterule is somehow problematic for jsf

Comment: Why is your image src ending with *.xhtml? That causes  the request to be mapped to faces servlet?

Comment: can you post the source of xhtml page, calling the image logo.png

Comment: yes jsf needs *.xhtml to parse the request. I have added the resource path and the source of the xhtml page. But the biggest issue are the resources from richfaces which cant be found. I checked also the permissions to the project folder and they are fine.